# Sort out dates with different formats Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am having a hard time trying to sort dates with different formats. I have a Series with inputs containing dates in many different formats and need to extract them and sort them chronologically.
So far I have setup different regex for fully numerical dates (01/01/1989), dates with month (either Mar 12 1989 or March 1989 or 12 Mar 1989) and dates where only the year is given (see code below)

```
pat1=r'(\d{0,2}[/-]\d{0,2}[/-]\d{2,4})' # matches mm/dd/yy and mm/dd/yyyy
pat2=r'((\d{1,2})?\W?(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*\W+(\d{1,2})?\W?\d{4})' 
pat3=r'((?<!\d)(\d{4})(?!\d))'
finalpat=pat1 + "|"+ pat2 + "|"  + pat3
df2=df1.str.extractall(finalpat).groupby(level=0).first()
```

I now got a dataframe with the different regex expressions above in different columns that I need to transform in usable times.

The problem I have is that I got dates like *Mar 12 1989* and *12 Mar 1989*  and *Mar 1989* (no day) in the same column of my dataframe.
Without two formats ( Month dd YYYY and dd Month YYYY) I can easily do this :

```
df3=df2.copy()

dico={"Jan":'01','Feb':'02','Mar':'03','Apr':'04','May':'05','Jun':'06','Jul':'07','Aug':'08','Sep':'09','Oct':'10','Nov':'11','Dec':'12'}


df3[1]=df3[1].str.replace("(?<=[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2})\w*","")  # we replace the month in the column by its number, and remove
for key,item in dico.items():                          # the letters in month after the first 3.
    df3[1]=df3[1].str.replace(key,item)
df3[1]=df3[1].str.replace("^(\d{1,2}/\d{4})",r'01/\g<1>')

df3[1]=pd.to_datetime(df3[1],format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')  # add 01 if no day given
```

where df3[1] is the column of interest. I use a dictionary to change Month to their number and get my dates as I want them.
The problem is that with two formats of dates ( Mar 12 1989 and 12 Mar 1989), one of the two format will be wrongly transformed.

Is there a way to discriminate between the date formats and apply different transformations accordingly ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What about normalizing your data first and then process with normalized date format?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski is right. If you normalise to YYYYMMDD you can sort lexicographically

Answer (score 1):

> problem I have is that I got dates like Mar 12 1989 and 12 Mar 1989
> and Mar 1989 (no day) in the same column of my dataframe.

[`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) can cope with that, consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'d_str':["Mar 12 1989", "12 Mar 1989", "Mar 1989"]})
df['d_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df.d_str)
print(df)
```

output

```
         d_str       d_dt
0  Mar 12 1989 1989-03-12
1  12 Mar 1989 1989-03-12
2     Mar 1989 1989-03-01
```

Now you can sort using `d_dt` as it has type `datetime64[ns]` but you must keep in mind that lack of day is treated as 1st day of given month. Be warned though it might fail if your data contain dates in [middle-endian](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/middle-endian.html) format (mm/dd/yy).

Comment: FML...and also thanks a lot !
I was trying to use pd.to_datetime with specific formating ( %m/%d%Y) which is why my program was failing on half the values.